# How to run PING command and get ping host summary?

Tags: java, command-line, ping

Hi I need to execute the `PING` command using Java code and get summary of the ping host. How to do it in Java?

Comment: @bhesh-gurung I started a small java library https://code.google.com/p/jpingy/ . Still a lot of work (started today)

Answer (score 19):

as viralpatel specified you can use `Runtime.exec()`

following is an example of it

```
class pingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ip = "127.0.0.1";
        String pingResult = "";

        String pingCmd = "ping " + ip;
        try {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                pingResult += inputLine;
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

**output**

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

refer http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t146589-ping-class-java.html

Comment: i want to append its output in html instead of println when i try to do it it keeps on executing for a long time then i cancel it !

Comment: what should i do for appending it to html?

Comment: i think you are working with `servlet` then you can add the text to the servlet html using printwriter object

Comment: can you help me in this regard?

Comment: i have not idea about it thats why i ask it from you

Comment: i call method from jsp and at server side i append string and that string i return it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6600/discussion-between-hemant-metalia-and-salman-raza)

Answer (score 5):

`InetAddress` class has a method which uses ECMP Echo Request (aka ping) to determine the hosts availability.

```
String ipAddress = "192.168.1.10";
InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
boolean reachable = inet.isReachable(5000);
```

If the above `reachable` variable is true, then it means that the host has properly answered with ECMP Echo Reply (aka pong) within given time (in millis).

**Note:** Not all implementations have to use ping. [The documentation states that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29):

> A typical implementation will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege
>   can be obtained, otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection
>   on port 7 (Echo) of the destination host.

Therefore the method can be used to check hosts availability, but it can not universally be used to check for ping-based checks.

Comment: Under Windows it seems java doesn't use ping and default to the TCP connection on port 7, which is usually blocked by a firewall. Under Unix the ping requires root access and therefore usually also default to port 7. Therefore isReachable is useless in production environements.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this ping library for java I'm making:

http://code.google.com/p/jpingy/

Maybe it can help

Comment: It only supports UNIX? You should include Windows support as well if you want your library to be useful...

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work on both Windows and Linux system,

```
public static boolean isReachable(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
        if (!url.contains("http") && !url.contains("https")) {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        url = urlObj.getHost();
        url = "ping " + url;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(url);
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                if (s.contains("Packets: Sent") || s.contains("bytes of data")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: vulnerable to command injection, `s.contains("bytes of data")` will be on every ping output on windows, regardless of up or down state. Thus this code will always return true except if the process fails to start