# Getting a Ping result in Java

Tags: java, networking

I'm want to write a program that sends ping to some network components and says if there "alive" by pinging them.
I want the pinging to be by an IP adress, and just get the result.
I tried searching the web for a clear answer about pinging in Java but it was all unclear to me.
I need someone can explain to me how it is done and add an example of the code

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: Uhhh.. If you are using windows, you could probably use `ProcessBuilder

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run PING command and get ping host summary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815012/how-to-run-ping-command-and-get-ping-host-summary)

Answer (score 1):

That is a piece of code to send ping in java.

```
String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
inet.isReachable(5000);
```

Comment: Is reachable returns a boolean of the connection status on the giving time? (5000ms)?

Comment: at the documentation states: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int) `The timeout value, in milliseconds, indicates the maximum amount of time the try should take. If the operation times out before getting an answer, the host is deemed unreachable. A negative value will result in an IllegalArgumentException being thrown.`

Comment: It doesn't use ICMP ping unless you are running as super-user on *nix.