# Javafx get Ping Result

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, ping

I have written a class to ping an IP address that i provide, but it won't return anything.
I tried adding a few markers to see where it goes wrong, but not even that worked...
I have a gui interface and I use a Label to write my data out (the same format worked before with a string), here is the code. There were certain lines that i did or did not want, hence the "relevant" integer, you may ignore it. This should run on ubuntu 13.10.

```
public static ArrayList<String> PingIpAddr(String string) throws IOException{
        String s = new String();
        int relevant =0;
        ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
        List.add("it happens \n");
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ProcessBuilder(string).start().getInputStream()));
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null){
             List.add("does this happen? \n");
            relevant++;
            if( (relevant == 2) || (relevant == 3) || (relevant == 4) || (relevant == 5) || (relevant == 6) || (relevant == 9) ){List.add(s + "\n");
            List.add("or this? \n");}}  //end of while
        List.add("This must happen! \n");
        return List;}   //end of Ping
```

and if this would work, here is where it would be implemented:

```
    String test;
    test = PingIp.testPingIpAddr("ping -c 5 4.2.2.2").toString();
    TeltonikaPing.setWrapText(true);
    TeltonikaPing.setText(test);
```

Strangely it doesn't give back a sigle line. Maybe I'm just missing something very basic?:/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the main issue is caused by the fact ping has a delay in most cases, try making use of stdInput.ready().
2. I would probably pass this to ProcessBuilder: new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2"); split out the command ping from its parameters.

as in - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

I hope this helps (:

Edit -- (this works below)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pinger
{
    public static List<String> PingIpAddr(String ip) throws IOException
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ping", ip);
        //ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ping", "-c 5", ip);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.start().getInputStream()));        

        while (!stdInput.ready())
        {
            // custom timeout handling
        }

        String line;
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

        while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
        {
            output.add(line);
        }

        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        List<String> lines = Pinger.PingIpAddr("127.0.0.1");

        for (String line : lines)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does ^^ and as soon as i get this working, I'll mark this as an answer. Sadly i don't have the rep yet to upvote it :D

Comment: I tried but the problem remains, i modified it to this:

Comment: public static ArrayList<String> testPingIpAddr(String string) throws IOException{
  String s = new String();
  ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
  List.add("it happens \n");
     BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ProcessBuilder("ping -c 5 " + string ).start().getInputStream()));

Comment: while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null){
      List.add("does this happen? \n");
      if(stdInput.ready() == false){
       List.add("or this? \n");
       try {Thread.sleep(1500);}
       catch(InterruptedException ex) {Thread.currentThread().interrupt();};} // end of if
      List.add(s + "\n");
      List.add("This must happen! \n");} //end of while
     List.add("ping -c 5 " + string + "\n");
     return List;} //end of Ping

Comment: Other than this i wasn't able to make heads or tails of the oracle doc.. sorry :(

Comment: Thank you Very Much ^^ It works perfectly. And to think a simple while was all i needed :D

Answer (score 1):

I found a nother solution, that lets me enter how long i want the Ping to be.

[How to run PING command and get ping host summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815012/how-to-run-ping-command-and-get-ping-host-summary)

if anyone else needs to incorporate it into a GUI :)