# Hiding subprocesses (child) inside parent process

Tags: java

How can I run subprocess in such a way that parent name gets "javaapp" and the subprocesses running under the parent process will be hidden and will not be seen in the task-manager?

Suppose I want to call a proccess that holds 2 subproccesses, each one of then is a ping command
Until now I have managed to run only one proccess (and its name is visible in the task manager)
From the following link:

[How to run PING command and get ping host summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815012/how-to-run-ping-command-and-get-ping-host-summary)

Comment: Besides the fact that, as correctly pointed out by Jim Garrison, this is not possible, there should also never be a situation where you need to hide some process behind another. Could you maybe elaborate what you want to achieve as I am genuinely curious.

Comment: And maybe then we can help you with what you might want to do in order to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Processes are managed by the OS and will always be displayed in the task manager or other process display tool (i.e. `ps` on Linux).

You cannot "hide" a process, that would enable malware.

Comment: While I do agree with you in general, there is a theoretical possibility to hide a process from at least the (windows) task manager by using a custom rootkit that replaces the `EnumProcesses()` method with an own implementation. I would never recommend doing so in any genuine software but saying it's straight up not possible only is half the truth. Compare this post for more information: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48184/hiding-process-from-task-manager

Comment: Of course, if you allow a rootkit anything is possible. Your question is tagged `java`

Comment: It's not my question. And yes, obviously this means including a rootkit. I just wanted to point out that making a generic argument of "is not possible" is simply only half the truth. It is possible, just not with a simple method call in Java.