# How to check internet connection using network device in java?

Tags: java, networking

i need to check internet connection without push URL. how can i check internet connection using interface device or something else.
i try using this code but it is not working while internet is not available. please help me.

```
try {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces;
    interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while(interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
        if (iface.isUp() && !iface.isLoopback()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "connect");

        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "connect first");
}
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to use `ping`, by spawning a new process. Have you tried that?

Comment: will you give me en example ?

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815012/how-to-run-ping-command-and-get-ping-host-summary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run PING command and get ping host summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815012/how-to-run-ping-command-and-get-ping-host-summary)

Answer (score 0):

check this example without pushing url:

```
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class CheckInternetConnection{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = null;

        try {   
            interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {  
            NetworkInterface nic = interfaces.nextElement();   
            System.out.print("Interface Name : [" + nic.getDisplayName() + "]");     
            try {    
                 System.out.println(", is connected : [" + nic.isUp() + "]"); 
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: i just want if network is connected then new swing interface is visible other wise it is postponed